# Replace coordinate references with named ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge xlsm file with about a 10,000 named ranges and 22 worksheets. I need to replace the coordinate references in formulas with the corresponding named ranges. I have tried this script:

```
Sub Ref2Named()
    Dim Nm As Name
    For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        ActiveSheet.Cells.ApplyNames Names:=Nm.Name
    Next Nm
End Sub
```

But it returns error 1004 Microsoft Excel cannot find any references to replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the entire code could possibly be replaced by the single line:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.ApplyNames
```

with no sub at all required. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196578.aspx) describes the name parameter as "An array of the names to be applied. If this argument is omitted, all names on the sheet are applied to the range." But -- it isn't clear that this would apply every name in the *workbook's* name collection.

If you do need a sub -- note that the documentation refers to using an *array* of names. For this you can use the `Array` function:

```
Sub Ref2Named()
    Dim Nm As Name
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        ActiveSheet.Cells.ApplyNames Names:=Array(Nm.Name)
    Next Nm
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I'm not a fan of `On Error Resume Next` but in this case I think it appropriate since the `ApplyNames` seems to fail if the name doesn't actually appear in any formula in the range.

If the names are references to ranges in other sheets, it seems to be a limitation of `ApplyNames` that it only replaces names with references to the current sheet. A workaround is to use Find and Replace:

```
Sub Ref2Named()
    Dim Nm As Name, ref As String
    With ActiveSheet.Cells
        For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
            On Error Resume Next
                .ApplyNames Names:=Array(Nm.Name)
            On Error GoTo 0
            ref = Nm.RefersTo
            ref = Mid(ref, 2)
            .Replace What:=ref, Replacement:=Nm.Name
            ref = Replace(ref, "$", "")
            .Replace What:=ref, Replacement:=Nm.Name
        Next Nm
    End With
End Sub
```

If, for example, the name `test` refersto `Sheet2!$A$1` then I am first assigning this reference to `ref` (after stripping off the leading `=` in `RefersTo`). Then if any cell in Sheet1 (assuming this is the active sheet) has either `Sheet2!A1` or `Sheet2$A$1`, this will be replaced by `test` in the formula. I am still keeping the `ApplyNames` for the local names.

To apply to all worksheets in the workbook, try:

```
Sub ApplyAllNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Nm As Name, ref As String
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.Cells
            For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
                On Error Resume Next
                    .ApplyNames Names:=Array(Nm.Name)
                On Error GoTo 0
                ref = Nm.RefersTo
                ref = Mid(ref, 2)
                .Replace What:=ref, Replacement:=Nm.Name
                ref = Replace(ref, "$", "")
                .Replace What:=ref, Replacement:=Nm.Name
            Next Nm
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

If some of your names are e.g. column absolute but not absolute, this code would need to be tweaked.

On Edit: Here is a version which should be able to handle large spreadsheets. To use it, add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (under `Tools/References` in the VBA editor):

```
Sub ApplyAllNames()
    Dim D As New Dictionary
    Dim C As Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim A As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim nm As Name, i As Long, n As Long, ref As String
    Dim R As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set C = New Collection
        D.Add ws.Name, C
    Next ws
    For Each nm In Names
        ref = Split(nm.RefersTo, "!")(0) '=sheet name of ref
        ref = Mid(ref, 2) 'get rid of "="
        D(ref).Add nm
    Next nm

    'replace each collection of names
    'by an array sorted in order of descending length
    Set sh = Worksheets.Add
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> sh.Name Then
            Set C = D(ws.Name)
            n = C.Count
            If n = 0 Then
                D(ws.Name) = Array()
            Else
                ReDim A(1 To n, 1 To 2)
                For i = 1 To n
                    A(i, 1) = C(i).Name
                    A(i, 2) = Len(C(i).RefersTo)
                Next i
                Set R = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(n, 2))
                R.Value = A
                R.Sort key1:=Range("B1:B" & n), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
                A = R.Value
                D(ws.Name) = A
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    sh.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'now loop over sheets and name array
    For Each ws In Sheets
        For Each sh In Sheets
            A = D(sh.Name)
            If ws.Name = sh.Name Then
                On Error Resume Next
                    For i = 1 To UBound(A)
                        ws.Cells.ApplyNames A(i, 1)
                    Next i
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                For i = 1 To UBound(A)
                    Set v = Names(A(i, 1))
                    ref = Mid(v.RefersTo, 2) 'name with "=" removed
                    ws.Cells.Replace ref, v.Name
                    ref = Replace(ref, "$", "")
                    ws.Cells.Replace ref, v.Name
                Next i
            End If
            Debug.Print ws.Name & " <- " & sh.Name
            DoEvents
        Next sh
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

The code splits the names into piles according to the sheet containing the range that the name refers to. Then it does the application incrementally, with a progress indicator in the immediate window. For example, `Sheet3 <- Sheet5` means that names referring to Sheet5 have been applied to formulas in Sheet 3. A subtle bug has been fixed. Some ranges might have addresses which are *prefixes* of other range address. The earlier code might e.g. replace `"Sheet2!A5" in the middle of a formula involving`"Sheet2!A55`by a name (say "foo_bar") leaving`"Sheet2!foo_bar5"` in the cell. The fix was to *sort* names in the order of decreasing reference length.

I tried the above code on a workbook with 11 sheets, 10,000 named ranges and 5,000 formulas, each of which refers to 5 randomly chosen cells in such a way that over 20,000 replacements need to be made. It takes about 4 minutes. If this one doesn't work, the natural next step would be to use regular expressions to extract cell references from each formula and comparing these references to a dictionary of name references.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the code does not work. No errors but no reference is replaced with name range either.

Comment: @mutant That's odd. I tested it and it worked. Maybe you can edit your post and give both an example of a name and an example of the formula that you expect to be modified by the sub. Also -- what happens if you run the code after removing the `On Error Resume Next` (but keeping the `Array`)?

Comment: The xlsm contained some weird macros with worksheet protection - i removed them and now your script works but only on the current sheet is it possible to crawl all the worksheets in the file? Another thing i got some formulas that refere cells on another sheet - is it possible to replace them too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mutant Hopefully the edited code will work for all names

Comment: @mutant Finally -- I added a tweak to iterate this over all worksheets

Comment: i tried the iterating script it runs about 7-8 minutes and ends with "Runtime error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error " and i dont see any changes on the formula references.

Comment: @mutant It needs some debugging then. Does it fail on a certain sheet? Is that sheet protected? Does it fail with a certain name? If so, what? Does it fail on a specific line of code? If so,  look at the values of the variables in break mode. Could be any number of things.

Comment: I cant understand if it fails on certain sheet or name - no sheets are protected i have removed all the protection.When it stops and i press "debug" i shows the first ".Replace What:=ref, Replacement:=Nm.Name"

Comment: Does it correctly process sheets before hitting an error? Put `Debug.Print ws.Name` after the line `For Each ws in Worksheets.Names` so you can tell the problem sheet. When you get to debug mode hover the mouse over `ref` to see what it is and open up the `locals window` to inspect what `Nm` is. See if you can reproduce the error with a very simple spreadsheet. Since I have no idea what the error is I don't know how to debug it. You could try t wrap it in an error handler.

Comment: I was able the locate and delete the problematic named range now the script runs for hours (two by now) the excel app becomes unresponsive and finally i killed it. I guess my excel table is too complicated (around 10 000 named ranges 5000 complex formulas and about 50 000 cells). I accept your answers as your script runs flawlessly on a simple 4 sheet 20 named ranges and 5 formulas file that i created for testing. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @mutant Don't give up so easily. For one thing -- if you haven't done so already, disable all screen-updating, automatic computation, and event-handlers during the execution of the loop. It shouldn't take hours to do what you want to do. Also, I have some ideas for a dictionary-based approach (e.g. iterate through the names once to build up a dictionary keyed by the addresses of the ranges that they refer to and then iterate through the cells once, checking any addresses they contain against the dictionary).

Comment: I have left the script to run over the night and after several hours ~5 it stopped with the "Runtime error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error ". I have removed the problematic named space so i will wait to see if the script passes further. Can you give me some example for the dictionary-based approach thank you.

Comment: @mutant See if the modified code works. It is a fairly involved problem. I think that further speed-up is possible, though I no longer have time to think about it.